# Using Repositories and service references in MVC controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, design-patterns, repository

I'm having some trouble with deciding on a solution for my mvc application.

Background.

We have an EF model which we perform operations on via WCF Services (not data services).

I have an MVC application which has a number of Repositories that talk directly to the Services and return WCF types back to a controller which is calling the repository method, a type called for example WCFUserEntity (it's not actually prefixed with WCF).

Inside the controller I plan to automap the WCFUserEntity to a ViewModel entity.

What is bugging me about this solution is that because i'm returning WCFUserEntity to the controller I have to have a reference to the WebService proxy in my controller which doesn't sit well with me, i'd like my controllers to know nothing of where the repository has got the data from. So another option for me is to do the automapping inside of the repository and return the ViewModel entity to the controller, i can't find much around which supports this idea though, so really what i'm looking for is validation of this 2nd solution or help with a 3rd.

thanks, Dom

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider a third option.

The use of ViewModelBuilders.

in your controller they would work like this:

var myViewModel = myViewModelBuilder.WithX().WithY().Build();

WithX and WithY would be methods that would add stuff to your viewmodel internally (within the builder, for example WithCountriesList() if you want to add a dropdown showing the countries in your view) and the Build method would return the internal viewmodel after adding all the bits with the WithXXX methods. This is so because most of the time you may want to add lists for dropdowns and things that are not part of your original model (your userEntity in this case).

This way, your controller doesn't know anything about how to build the viewmodel, your repository is also agnostic of viewmodels. All the work is done in the Builder. On the downside, you need to create a ViewModelBuilder for each ViewModel.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting. I see what you're saying re the Builder method but I can't see how it would be any different to having the repository build up the ViewModel, considering the Builder would have to know of both WCF Service and ViewModel types.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way around that. At some point in your application you'll have to convert one to the other and at that point you'll need to know about both. By doing it in the builder you separate concerns, controller does the controlling, repository returns data and the builder builds your viewmodels. Your controller would not know anything about your WCF entities so depending on your architecture you may not have to add references to them. By putting your builder and repositories in another layer, you limit the scope of your WCF entities.

Answer (score 0):

How I would approach this might require some architecture changes, but I would suggest you approach your WCF API to return ViewModels instead of entities.

For starters, think about bandwidth issues (which would be an issue if you are hosting the WCF in Azure or the cloud).  If your ViewModel is only using a few specific properties, why waste the bandwidth returning the other data?  In high traffic scenarios, this could cause a waste of traffic that could end up costing money.  For example, if your view is only display a user and his questions, there's no reason to send his email, answers, point count, etc.. over the wire.

Another issue to think about is eager loading.  By having the WCF service return a ViewModel, you know you have all the data (even when it pertains to related entities) required from the view in one trip to the WCF service.  You do not need to get the `WCFUserEntity` and then ask WCF for `WCFDocumentEntities` that are related to that specific user.

Finally, if your WCF API is built around ViewModels then you have a MUCH clearer understanding of the business processes involved.  You know that this specific request (and view in the system) will give you this specific information, and if you need different information for a different view then you know that it's a completely different business request that has different business requirements.  Using stack overflow as an example, it makes it trivial to see that this business process is asking for the current user with his related questions, while this business process is requesting the current user with his related answers.

Using ViewModels in your data retrieval WCF API means that your frontend layers do not necessarily know where the data came from, it just knows that it called a business process and got the data it needs.  As far as it knows the data layer connected to the database directly instead of WCF.

**Edit:**
After re-reading, this actually looks like your 3rd option.  Most research on the net don't talk about this option, and I don't know why, but after having some similar frustrations you are having (plus others listed in this post) this is the way I have gone with my business layer.  It makes more sense and is actually (imho) easier to manage.

Comment: Hi @KallDrex, thanks for your answer, sounds like an ideal solution . What I should have said is the WCF services are also being consumed by wpf apps and also part of a WF4 state machine and unfortunately pretty much complete, all of the members are required at some point too so i'm stuck with them.

Comment: Ah yeah, that makes this impracticable, unfortunately.  This is mostly good upon early development of the architecture.